# Best approach to allow front-end display of posts’ reviewers?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, multi-author

My first question here; please forgive any protocol lapses.

I manage an academic journal that publishes on Wordpress. We use Co-Authors Plus to allow collaborative articles. Each article also has two or more peer reviewers, who currently have entries as “Speakers”, a custom post type created by the theme we use: The Keynote from Goodlayers.

I want to attach metadata to each article to identify its reviewers, ultimately to display that information to readers on the front end. (For now, we manually write the reviewers’ names at the end of the article.)

Several potential solutions come to mind, but I’m not advanced/familiar enough to know how best to proceed. Should I:

- Manually create a custom non-hierarchical taxonomy called “Reviewers” and manually add a list of names?
- Use a plugin like [Types](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/getting-starting-with-types/) to somehow establish the link between the “Speakers” post type and the article posts? ([This information](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/getting-started-views/part-9-many-many-relationships/) about an intermediary object feels more complex than needed, and I have no clue how I’d access the data to display it on the front end.)
- Do something else I’ve not thought of yet?

Basically, I’ve grown accustomed to the simplicity of Co-Authors Plus and my ability to associate “Guest Authors” as authors of each article. Ultimately, I’d like the same functionality associating “Speakers” as reviewers of each article, too. But I know the simplicity of Co-Authors Plus comes from the extensive coding that supports it.

What’s the best/simplest way to associate a custom post type with regular posts in a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a answer in development then I read what you were looking for some more. I will need more info before I can help.

Is a reviewer/speaker a custom post type or a user?

Is this relationship only going to be displayed on the article. Or will you also be displaying it on the Guest Authors/Speakers page as well?

Comment: The reviewer/speaker is a custom post type.

The relationship **needs** to be displayed on the article page — I want to credit the reviewers next to where I credit the author.

Being able to view a list of reviewed articles for each reviewer would be neat for down the road expansion, but that's not the critical issue at hand immediately. I could live without this functionality.

Comment: I would use post meta to save the data. You can add post meta to the post with the post_id of the custom post type (reviewer) update_post_meta() and use get_post_meta() to retrieve and display it on the post. Use the wordpress save post_post hook to save the data. if you need an example I can edit my answer above.

Comment: Okay, I think I follow. Your suggestion of using post meta avoids creating a new taxonomy. To facilitate accurate data entry, I think I need to make a custom post meta box, allowing me to choose a reviewer name from a list, rather than remember post_id values. Following [a tutorial like this one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) should guide me through the details. Does that sound like what you were suggesting? (Just making sure I understand…you’re in unfamiliar territory for me.)

Comment: yes, if there is no automated way to handle this (like during post save or review) then using a custom meta box to add the post_meta is the best method.